Selenium Not Working! selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
I am learning python and tring to use selenium login chrome account. Here is my option code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/07080/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/")
chrome_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://x.com/home")
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]


I sucessfully opened the chorome browser with my profie account. However, my code crashed and did not open x.
here is the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Python 100 Day\Day17\Quiz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Python 100 Day\Day17\Quiz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Python 100 Day\Day17\Quiz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\07080\Desktop\Python 100 Day\Day17\Quiz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Python 100 Day\Day17\Quiz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Python 100 Day\Day17\Quiz\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D68923+23283]
    (No symbol) [0x00D2E934]
    (No symbol) [0x00C60733]
    (No symbol) [0x00C91075]
    (No symbol) [0x00C8BAE9]
    (No symbol) [0x00CCD9ED]
    (No symbol) [0x00CCD21A]
    (No symbol) [0x00CC41B6]
    (No symbol) [0x00C98017]
    (No symbol) [0x00C9890D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E5A5F3+1013699]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E63E4C+1052700]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E5D4B4+1025668]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D8EA2B+179195]
    (No symbol) [0x00D36833]
    (No symbol) [0x00D33198]
    (No symbol) [0x00D33337]
    (No symbol) [0x00D2B4BE]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76F57BA9+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77A3C10B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x77A3C08F+191]

I tried add argument but not working.
